# *= - что это значит?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Что значит данный код:

```
*=
```

Пример:

```
$n *= $r / 100;
```

Comment: Это отражённый целующий смайлик) как `=*`, только наоборот) а если серьёзно, то http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp вторая таблица.

Comment: Вдобавок к ответам: наследие языка C (его рекомендуется знать, тогда многие унаследованные от него приколы понять легче)

Comment: да, многие языки используют эти конструкции)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$n умножить на то, что стоит после =

этож азы..

```
Assignment    Same as:
$a += $b     $a = $a + $b    Addition
$a -= $b     $a = $a - $b     Subtraction
$a *= $b     $a = $a * $b     Multiplication
$a /= $b     $a = $a / $b    Division
$a %= $b     $a = $a % $b    Modulus

See the String Operators page(http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)
$a .= $b     $a = $a . $b       Concatenate

See the Bitwise Operators page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)
$a &= $b     $a = $a & $b     Bitwise And
$a |= $b     $a = $a | $b      Bitwise Or
$a ^= $b     $a = $a ^ $b       Bitwise Xor
$a <<= $b     $a = $a << $b     Left shift
$a >>= $b     $a = $a >> $b      Right shift
```