# Что в php означает ".=" ?

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$log .= "<li>Пожалуйста, введите Ваш email!</li>";
```

Что в php означает ".=" и в отдельности "." ?

Comment: $text.=$newtext ~ $text=$text+$newtext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"." - оператор конкатенации строк.
`$log .= "<li>Пожалуйста, введите Ваш email!</li>";` - то же самое, что и `$log = $log."<li>Пожалуйста, введите Ваш email!</li>";`

Answer (score 3):

[Вы издеваетесь?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150932/php-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82) Недавно был такой же вопрос, поиск рулит.

Comment: почитайте по приведенной мной ссылке, там расписан не только этот вопрос, но и те, которые возникнут в дальнейшем по схожим функциям ;)

Answer (score 1):

Присоединение строки с присваиванием.
Присоединение строки -

```
"<p>".$str."</p>";
```

например.

Comment: какой-то не удачный пример...

Comment: Это ж чем он неудачный? Тут к куску строки с <p> присоединяется например  текст, который мы хотим поместить между <p></p> а потом добавляем и кусок с закрывающим тегом. Вот тот же пример но с echo:  
    $str = "Hello World";
    echo("<p>".$str."</p>");

Answer (score 0):

.= - это как +=, только в отношении строк. Т.е., это оператор конкатенации "новой" строки к уже существующей. "Новая" справа, существующая - слева

Comment: @nolka, То есть, по Вашему описанию, конструкция вида `$str1 .= $str2;` работать не будет?

Comment: по моему описанию эта конструкция, как раз-таки, работать будет

Comment: @nolka, ну вы описали операнд конкатенации, как "новая строка" - поэтому и предположил. Выражайтесь точнее:)